# REG QUERY for unknown uninstall ID

Tags: command-line, uninstallation, sccm-2007

I have been searching and searching and have not come up with a good answer. I am trying to query the registry in both the locations for a software's UninstallString.

```
-HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall 
-HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

The `UninstallString` needs to be set to a variable or piped straight in to run the `msiexec.exe /x {GUID} /qn`.

I would prefer this to be in powershell or command just my ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "uninstall1=" 
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN (
   'REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /v Uninstall'
) DO (set Uninstall1=%%B)

set uninstall
```

This should retrieve the first string, if it exists.

Repeat the formula for the second string. The final `SET uninstall` is merely to report the environment variables starting `UNINSTALL` for verification.

Then

```
if defined Uninstall1 msiexec ... "%Uninstall1%"
```

should execute `MSIEXEC` with the parameters you require (where ... are your options - /x, /qn whatever)